# How do I sort an active record collection by a value held by one of its associations?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sorting, activerecord, associations

I have an Active Record Model called `Owner`. It is associated with both a `House` and a `CoOwner`. An `Owner` also has a column called `debt_amount`. In my case, every `Owner` will always be attached to both a `House` and a `CoOwner`

A house has a `location` field

I am looking to run a query to find all Owners attached to a specific co-owner, with nil for debt_amount. This is working fine.

Where I am running into trouble is when I attempt to sort this the associated `Houses.location`.

Below is what I am currently using.

```
Owner.includes(:house).where(co_owner_id: 10)
     .where.not(debt_amount: nil)
     .order([house.location])
```

Any ideas on how to make this work, or pointers to resources I can use to do some reading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Owner.includes(:house)
     .where(co_owner_id: 10)
     .where.not(debt_amount: nil)
     .order("houses.location ASC")
```

Here are more examples, https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order

Comment: Wow, What I was doing wrong was using "house.location" as opposed to "houses.location". 

What a face palm moment. Thanks for the help.